# Segmented Control Position Changes With Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uistoryboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I have built a simple IOS app to coordinate with my bluetooth device that I built. In doing so, I use segmented control on the main storyboard to turn it on and off, which works just fine. I can then move to a settings page which has another segmented control box, which stays in its current position only if I move forward in the storyboard. If I move back to the main screen then go back to settings, it is in its first position, not the last position where it was placed.

Shortly after, I thought it could be that the segment was not connected to the ViewController.swift, but after trying to connect it in the same manner as before, my app kept crashing whenever I tried accessing settings.
[image: Storyboard layout]
[Settings.swift Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmxq4.png)

Comment: Can you share your code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving the segment state ?

Have you try save your last state in UserDefaults and load it?
https://medium.com/@nimjea/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79

I hope you fix this.

Comment: I have updated it and it works, but if the segmented control was "on" it will appear at "off" then go to "on" shortly after the page loads. I am assuming this is due to the way that I have it set up.